# Semantic image segmentation for mobile device

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I want to separate front object(only human) in a image from background in a pixel level.

There are already many good deep learning models like below showing great result:
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~szheng/crfasrnndemo/

But their model is too big(500M), I need a solution that works on mobile device, a model that is small and fast. I do not need many classification, only human and background.

Does anyone know any good solution/study that can fulfill my needs?

Comment: your question is off-topic. use websearch

Comment: I did extensive search and did not find any related paper or code can fulfill my needs.  That's why I post the question here.